# How to remove commas from a line and write it to an output file

Tags: java

This is my assignment - Write a program that reads a file and removes all comma’s from it and writes it back out to a second file. It should print to the console window, at the end, the number of comma’s removed.
The program needs to:
 Prompt the user for the name of the file to read.
 Reads file
 Write the non-comma characters to output.txt, including all spaces.
 When done reading the input file, write the total number of comma’s removed to the console window.

For example, if the input file contains 3+,2 = 5m, 7%,6 =1 hello
Then the output.txt file should contain:

3+2=5m 7%6=1 hello
And the console window should print “Removed 3 commas”.

Right now I'm having trouble actually removing commas from my input file, I think I would write the line under my last if statment.

Tried figuring out how to remove commas from the input file

```
 package pkg4.pkg4.assignment;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

/**
 *
 * @author bambo
 */
public class Assignment {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
       Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in); 
       System.out.println("What is the name of the inputfile?");
       String inputfile = keyboard.nextLine();
       File f = new File(inputfile);
       Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(f);

         System.out.println("Please enter the output file");
         String outputfile = keyboard.nextLine();


         FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(outputfile);
         PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);


       int lineNumber=0;


       while(inputFile.hasNext());
        lineNumber++;
             int commacount = 0;

              String line = inputFile.nextLine();
             if (line.length () != 0)
                 commacount++;
              for(int i=0; i< line.length(); i++)
             {
                 if(line.charAt(i) == ',');
                 {
                     commacount++;
                 }

         pw.println("removed " + commacount + "commas");

    }

}
}
```

Comment: Add each letter to a `StringBuilder`. If the letter is a comma, increase count and *don't* add that letter to the builder. Write the builder contents to a file. Could also split using a comma as the delimiter - the amount of commas would be the length of the array minus 1. You could then simply print the array  contents of the split to a file.

Answer (score 1):

According to your requirement for program i am suggesting you to use java 8 classes.for simplicity.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Assignment {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String content = "";
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("What is the name of the input file?");
        String inputfile = keyboard.nextLine();
        content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(inputfile)));
        long total_numbers_of_char = content.chars().filter(num -> num == ',').count();
        System.out.println("Please enter the output file");
        content = content.replaceAll(",", "");
        String outputfile = keyboard.nextLine();
        Files.write(Paths.get(outputfile), content.getBytes());
        System.out.println("removed " + total_numbers_of_char + " commas");
        keyboard.close();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To print on console you should be using :

```
System.out.println("removed " + commacount + "commas");
```

To write the line in the output file without the commas :

```
pw.println(line.replaceAll(",",""));
```

Comment: I created a input and output file and added that line to the bottom of the project, now it just keeps running after I enter the names of the file. 
         pw.println("removed " + commacount + "commas");
         pw.println(line.replaceAll(",",""));
         pw.close();

Comment: Could it be this line?   if(line.charAt(i) == ','); ? Because my output file remains empty and I noticed you're using regular quotation marks in the println line. I tried switching them to regular on that line but I got an error